# extract data between similar patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use `sed` to print the contents between two patterns including **the first one**. I was using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or) as a source.

My file looks like this:

```
>item_1
abcabcabacabcabcabcabcabacabcabcabcabcabacabcabc
>item_2
bcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdb
>item_3
cdecde
>item_4
defdefdefdefdefdefdef
```

I want it to start searching from `item_2` (and include) and finish at next occuring `>` (not include). So my code is `sed -n '/item_2/,/>/{/>/!p;}'`.

The result wanted is:

```
item_2
bcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdb
```

but I get it without `item_2`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the awk method suggested by oguz for its simplicity. Now if you are interested in a sed way, out of curiosity, you could fix what you have already tried with a minor change :

```
sed -n '/^>item_2/ s/.// ; //,/>/ { />/! p }' input_file
```

The empty regex `//` recalls the previous regex, which is handy here to avoid duplicating `/item_2/`. But keep in mind that `//` is actually dynamic, it recalls the latest regex evaluated at runtime, which is *not* necessarily the closest regex on its left (although it's often the case). Depending on the program flow (branching, address range), the content of the same `//` can change and... actually here we have an interesting example ! (and I'm not saying that because it's my baby ^^)

On a line where `/^>item_2/` *matches*, the `s/.//` command is executed and the latest regex before `//` becomes `/./`, so the following address range is equivalent to `/./,/>/`.

On a line where `/^>item_2/` *does not match*, the latest regex before `//` is `/^>item_2/` so the range is equivalent to `/^>item_2/,/>/`.

To avoid confusion here as the effect of `//` changes during execution, it's important to note that an address range evaluates only its left side when not triggered and only its right side when triggered.

Comment: Does the OP require the removal of the `>` before `item_2`? What if there were 2 successive `item_2`'s?

Comment: @potong Ah that's right, I focused on the original sed command and did not notice that the leading `>` was not in the expected output. Well, as the answer is accepted, I guess that it was not a major concern but it's quite easy to fix so in doubt, and also to deal with possibly successive `item_2` patterns as you pointed out, I'll update the answer. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk, split input by `>`s and print part(s) matching `item_2`.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";ORS=""} /item_2/' file
item_2
bcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdbbcdbcdbcdbcdb
```

Comment: ok this worked well, thanks. But do you know why `sed` didn't work? just in principle or it's just wrong?

Comment: @Polina `/>/` matches the line containing `item_2` as well as the last line in the range (`>item_3`), thus it lets only the line between them out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;/^>item_2/{s/.//;:b;p;n;/^>/!bb;ba}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

If a line begins `>item_2`, remove the first character, print the line and fetch the next line

If that line does not begins with a `>`, repeat the last two instructions.

Otherwise, repeat the whole set of instructions.

If there will always be only one line following `>item_2`, then:

```
sed '/^>item_2/!d;s/.//;n' file
```